# How to log out of facebook sdk login when this error occurs?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I just tried implementing the Facebook login to my app and when I went to log in I got the "App Not Setup: This app is still in development mode..etc" but the issue I am having is that I believe I entered the wrong email (not my admin) email but am stuck on this error page.  Does anyone know how I can get back to the login page???

I have tried rerunning my app and I don't want to make my app public yet.

[image: my app]

Comment: I just went and erased all content and settings in the IOS simulator and it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is this in the simulator? Try deleting the app off the simulator and rebuilding/rereunning the app as that should present the login flow again and you can ensure you enter the proper email.

Comment: Yeah it was in the simulator, i just had to go to the "hardware" tab and 'erase all content and settings' and then rerun the app. thanks though!

Comment: I posted another question, if you could look at it and have any tips that would be great!